# How Postgres save data?

Tags: django, postgresql, forms

I have django-project where i have model:

```
class Example(models.Model):
  title = models.CharFied(blank=False, null=False)
```

I have a form associated with class Example, where input "title" is not required.

How postgres can save this empty data? I am afraid that I will have a lot of errors in future.

Answer (score 0):

Database backend will save data in which, only Example ids will be present (may be title, if submitted). So, yes you may have pretty useless data. I think there may be 1 or 2 solutions:

1. make title required field in your forms, with `required=True` argument
2. write management command, which will be called periodically and clean those unused records

Hope, it helps